# How to add a custom menu item to quickly add a custom tag

Tags: foobar2000

When you right-click on a track in Foobar2000 (v1.2.8) there is a context menu with the items like "Play", "Convert", "Utilities, "Properties" and so on.
I want to add a custom menu item, say "My commands" and there should be inner menu items like "Mark track as unique", "Mark track as rare", etc.

So I have 2 questions:

1. How can I add custom menu items
2. How can I write a script to save something to track's metadata (for example, add value "unique" to the comment metadata field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comrade Rollin on foobar's forum helped me out:

> Use Masstagger - http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_masstag
>   To create script: Right click->Tagging->Manage scripts
>   To use saved scripts: Right click->Tagging->Scripts->...

After that I could just add hot keys for quick access to the scripts.